# Как с помощью Java script убрать галочку в чекбоксе?

Tags: javascript

Имеется код:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="share" checked="checked">
```

Как с помощью кода js убрать checked?

Comment: `(как-то полученный input).checked = false` если нужно просто снять галочку, а не убирать атрибут (зы убирать атрибут нет никакого смысла)

Answer (score 1):

Метод [.checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#additional_attributes), задайте `true` - чтобы "включить" или `false` - чтобы "выключить".
Если просто обратится к методу, то вернет [булевое](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Glossary/Boolean) значение о состояние.

```js
var checkbox = document.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]');

setInterval(function() {
  checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked; // включит если выключен и наоборот.
}, 1000)
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="share" checked="checked">
```